# React native flushSync alternative

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I am refactoring my code after updating from react native 0.67 to 0.69.5, thus adding react 18 to the app. I have some code like the following, where `doSomething()` uses `userInfo` internally. The point is to make sure I'm only calling `doSomething()` when I have the most recent version of userInfo.

```
useEffect(() => {
   doSomething()
}, [userInfo])

const handleLoginButton = async () => {
   const info = await fetchUserInfo();
   setUserInfo(info);
}
```

Which I acknowledge that is a bad use of useEffect from recent discussions. So I wish to refactor to something like

```
const handleLoginButton = async () => {
    const info = await fetchUserInfo();
    flushSync(() => setUserInfo(info));
    doSomething();
}
```

But `flushSync` is imported from `react-dom`. I do know that I could just `doSomething(info)`, but that would need a lot more of refactoring in the actual code.
Is there any way of achieving this using `react-native` instead of `react-dom`?